# php include and variables

Tags: php, variables, include

Newby to php.  When I do an `include(<filename>)` are the contents of `<filename>` literally just pasted into the included-into file? I've noticed lots of examples where variables are mentioned in an include file and then referenced in the including file.

I come from the Java world where `import` just makes the classes defined in the imports available.

Just trying to wrap my head around it.

Specifically, I'm setting up my database connection and don't want to include the username/password in the php file (the php segments aren't actually sent to the client, right? ) It just feels...icky.

Thanks!

Comment: PHP code is executed on the server. Unless there's a failure or misconfiguration, the raw PHP code will NEVER be seen by the remote user, only the output of the code's execution.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> The include() statement includes and evaluates the specified file.
>
> The documentation below also applies to require().
>
> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include() will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include() construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require(), which will emit a fatal error.
>
> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.
>
> For more information on how PHP handles including files and the include path, see the documentation for include_path.
>
> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Comment: Please don't incorporate larger chunks from the manual that are actually the answer as the licensing of the manual is not compatible with SO. So please respect the rights of the authors and compile an answer of your own with appropriate quoting.

Comment: Can you direct me to the licensing conflict? Thanks.

Comment: Seems you're wrong. According to http://www.php.net/license/index.php#doc-lic, which links to http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/, "You are free: to Share — to copy, distribute and transmit the work, to Remix — to adapt the work, to make commercial use of the work" provided you attribute the use (which I did).

Comment: Well, I might have overlooked that commercial part, however [see the real license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/legalcode) for everything you need to keep to be allowed so. I normally do not consider it practicable feasible for just copy'n'paste answers.

Comment: I see your point, however the docs said it better than I could ;)

Comment: Yeah don't wanna blow this up too much. Probably it's better to leave just a comment with a link to the manual ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like the PHP manual said the raw php code will never be visible to the end user unless you specifically design your code to do so, including a file just includes the variables and functions of said file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to set your mind at ease because of hardcoded credentials then just be sure to chmod with proper permissions. Allow the owner to read and write and execute while disallowing everyone else from using the script.

http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/chmod.shtml